# Missing WebApiConfig.cs in App_Start. Can I use Startup.cs?

Tags: asp.net, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET Web Api v2 web app and I am trying to enable CORS so I can call the API's from a client on a different server.

I am following a tutorial located [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/08/31/how-to-enable-cors-in-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx) and it talks about adding the following lines of code to the `WebApiConfig.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder ...

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5901", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The problem is I don't have a `WebApiConfig.cs` in the App_Start directory. I do most of my configuration and routing in the `Startup.cs` file in the root of the web application. I don't recall ever using a `WebApiConfig.cs` file. Is this code something I can add to `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Yes, you can add it to `Startup.cs`. But `WebApiConfig.cs` is just a `public static class WebApiConfig` with whatever methods you want to include there.

Comment: @Jasen - Thanks! If I wanted to add `WebApiConfig.cs` and add only the above mentioned code is there a default method that needs to be included? I guess I am looking for where I would add the CORS code mentioned above? Is there a specific method that would need to be called? Also, add this as an answer and I will chose it so others can see it and you can get the credit.

Comment: I already have this line `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` in the Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method of the `Startup.cs`. Do i need to add more or should this be enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer of your question is simply: Yes, you can.

The only thing that matters is that you apply your settings to the same `HttpConfiguration` instance you will then pass to `app.UseWebApi()` extension method.

`WebApiConfig.cs` is just boilerplate file created by the default Web API template to separate Web API configuration from other configuration files. If you plan to ever use only Owin, than you can simply ignore it.

[Edit] Sample code, inside your `Startup.cs` `Configuration` method:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5901", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Responding to comments, if you use `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` then you are setting CORS headers at a higher level then Web API, and you will not need to use `EnableCorsAttribute` at all. The main difference in your case is that with `CorsAttribute` you'll have a fine graded configuration over the CORS header (e.g. you could set a different CORS header for every Action method).

Just remember to put `app.UseCors` before any other Owin middle-ware in your `Configuration` method.

Comment: In my case I am using the OWIN pipeline for authentication and token issuance. So are are you saying I would add 
`var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5901", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);` 
to the `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method in Startup.cs making sure the use the HttpConfiguration in place of the `config` object listed in the code? Also, is it needed if I have `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` already in the `Configuration` method?

Comment: Edited the answer after your comment.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks for the followup!